# Problems Importing a Library into Xcode

Tags: ios, import, libraries, sqlite

I am trying to import SQLite into an app in Xcode. The library has worked in previous iterations, but now I get an error that says "No such module SQLite" when I try to import the library at the top of the file I want to use it. I have followed the instructions on the gitHub page and still have trouble with the library. One thing that I notice is that in the file explorer the SQLite.framework files are highlighted in red. I believe this is the source of the problem however, I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Show us a screen shot. Give the link to the "GitHub" page.

Comment: What OS and version?